# Elasticsearch search query: why params._source.nested_field.size() is not working in script?

Tags: elasticsearch, scripting, nested, elasticsearch-painless

There are lot of questions and answers about this but still didn't get a satisfied answers. 
Elasticsearch version: 6.5

Index mapping

```
"_doc": {
    "properties": {
      "ssid": {
        "type": "long"
      },
      "nested_field": {
        "type": "nested"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": {
        "script": {
          "script": "params._source.nested_field.size() > 1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Also tried below query but no luck

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "nested_field",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "filter": {
                  "script": {
                    "script": "params._source.nested_field.size() > 1"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Error

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "script_exception",
        "reason": "runtime error",
        "script_stack": [
          "params._source.nested_field.size() > 1",
          "              ^---- HERE"
        ],
        "script": "params._source.nested_field.size() > 1",
        "lang": "painless"
      }
    ],
    "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
    "reason": "all shards failed",
    "phase": "query",
    "grouped": true,
    "failed_shards": [
      {
        "shard": 0,
        "index": "testing_index",
        "node": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "runtime error",
          "script_stack": [
            "params._source.nested_field.size() > 1",
            "              ^---- HERE"
          ],
          "script": "params._source.nested_field.size() > 1",
          "lang": "painless",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "null_pointer_exception",
            "reason": null
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "status": 500
}
```

params._source.nested_field return nested array while using in scripted_field but not working in validation query. Documentation are not complete about nested query with painless script.

Comment: In a filter context, Painless doesn't have access to the _source document: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/6.5/painless-filter-context.html, mainly for performance reasons.

Comment: What is the alternate way to validate the nested value?

Comment: Did you end up solving this? I have the same problem...

Comment: @Rob: No, We had moved on latest version 7.2 recently and I didn't yet tried the same script yet. will let you know if this works in latest version.
I really surprised that no one in world is interested in these kind of problems of elaticsearch.

Comment: @Avi now I have a similar problem - https://discuss.elastic.co/t/howto-filter-documents-contain-duplicates-in-array-with-painless/256829

Did you resolve yours one?

Comment: Avi & @RobL -- if you're still facing this problem check my answer below.

Answer (score 4):

Despite the fact that this would've been slow and [against the guidance](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-source) of *not* accessing `_source` in search queries, the query would have worked before v6.4.

After v6.4, thanks to an unintentional side effect of [refactoring](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-source), accessing `_source` in the script query context is not possible.

With that being said, you can "hijack" a `function_score` query whose Painless context *still* has access to the `_source`:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "functions": [
        {
          "script_score": {
            "script": {
              "source": "params._source.containsKey('nested_field') && params._source['nested_field'] != null && params._source.nested_field.size() > 1 ? 1 : 0"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "min_score": 1
    }
  }
}
```

---

You could use a `pipeline` to calculate the field size and then save it on the doc's top level.

Alternatively, you could use `copy_to` as outlined in [my related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64452344/8160318).