# How do I get the size of a 'nested' type array through a Painless script in Elasticsearch version 6.7?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using Elasticsearch version 6.7. I have the following mapping:

```
{
    "customers": {
        "mappings": {
            "customer": {
                "properties": {
                    "name": {
                        "type": "keyword"
                    },
                    "permissions": {
                        "type": "nested",
                        "properties": {
                            "entityId": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "entityType": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "permission": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "permissionLevel": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            },
                            "userId": {
                                "type": "keyword"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to run a query to that shows all customers who have > 0 permissions. I have tried the following:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": {
                "script": {
                    "script": {
                        "lang": "painless",
                        "source": "params._source != null && params._source.permissions != null && params._source.permissions.size() > 0"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But this returns no hits because `params._source` is null as Painless does not have access to the `_source` document according to [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022283/elasticsearch-search-query-why-params-source-nested-field-size-is-not-workin?rq=1). How can I write a Painless script that gives me all customers who have > 0 permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution 1: Using Script with must query

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "lang": "painless",
              "inline": """
                ArrayList st = params._source.permissions;
                if(st!=null && st.size()>0)
                  return true;
              """
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

### Solution 2: Using Exists Query on nested fields

You could simply make use of [`Exists`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) query something like the below to get customers who have > 0 permissions.

### Query:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
       {
        "nested": {
          "path": "permissions",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "exists":{
                    "field": "permissions.permission"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "exists":{
                    "field": "permissions.entityId"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "exists":{
                    "field": "permissions.entityType"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "exists":{
                    "field": "permissions.permissionLevel"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

## Solution 3: Create definitive structure but add empty values to the fields

Another alternative would be to ensure all documents would have the fields. 
Basically,

- Ensure that all the documents would have the `permissions` nested document
- However for those who would not have the permissions, just set the field `permissions.permission` to `0`
- Construct a query that could help you get such documents accordingly

Below would be a sample document for a user who doesn't have permissions:

```
POST mycustomers/customer/1
{
  "name": "john doe",
  "permissions": [
    {
      "entityId" : "null",
      "entityType": "null",
      "permissionLevel": 0,
      "permission": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

The query in that case would be as simple as this:

```
POST <your_index_name>/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "permissions",
            "query": {
              "range": {
                "permissions.permission": {
                  "gte": 1
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }    
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am a little confused about the 'permissions is not a field' statement you made. Can you please explain a bit more? To me it looks like another field, it's just a nested field. Obviously I am missing some knowledge here.

Comment: Hey @RobL, my apologies. I removed that part, what I was trying to say is that it is not a field that could be queried. I've added the script you are looking for, please check the `Solution 1` and let me know if that works.