# Elasticsearch conditional query : search nested if not exists check default value on parent

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch. I have a question about creating conditional search queries between nested and parent types.

I have a mapping below named "homes"

```rb
PUT /homes/_mapping
{
    "properties": {
        "name": { "type": "text" },
        "ownerID": { "type": "integer" },
        "status": { "type": "text" }, // active or inactive
        "minDays": { "type": "integer" },
        "dayData": {
            "type": "nested",
            "properties": {
              "date": { "type": "date"  },
              "minDays": { "type": "integer" },
              "closed": { "type": "boolean" }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Homeowners can define custom `minDays` for homes day by day. Of course, there is a default value for `minDays` in the parent.

I want to make a search query by date range

For example, users can search in homes by start and end date. If there is `dayData` defined with `minDays` on the start date, it will take the value here, if not, the parent value will be taken for filtering.

How can I achieve that?

**Update**

I have documents like below

For example if user is searching avaibility for the dates between "2021-01-01" and 2021-01-04. Total day count is "3" for requested dates. We need search for homes which has minDays value greater or equeal than "3".

In this situation:

1. I need to get docs with status is "active"
2. The min day value for _doc/1 is "2", cause there is a custom dayData value with minDays. So this property won't be available.
3. The min day value for _doc/2 is "4". We get default value from parent, cause there is no custom dayData value. This property will be available.
4. If they dayData includes a "closed" value with "true" between searched dates, home won't be available.

I have tried several search queries to achieve that but failed for this context.

Thank you in advance.

```rb
PUT homes/_doc/1
{
  "name" : "Home Test",
  "status" : "active",
  "ownerID": 1,
  "minDays" : "3",
  "dayData" : [
    {
      "date" : "2021-01-01",
      "minDays" : 2
    },
    {
      "date" : "2021-01-04",
      "minDays" : 5
    },
    {
      "date" : "2021-01-05",
      "closed": true
    }
  ]
}

PUT homes/_doc/2
{
  "name" : "Home Test 2",
  "status" : "active",
  "ownerID": 2,
  "minDays" : "4",
  "dayData" : [
    {
      "date" : "2021-05-02",
      "minDays" : 2
    },
    {
      "date" : "2021-05-03",
      "minDays" : 2
    },
    {
      "date" : "2021-05-03",
      "minDays" : 2,
      "closed" :true
    },
    {
      "date" : "2021-05-10",
      "minDays" : 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you also show some sample documents?

Comment: @val I have updated my question. Thank you for your help, in advance.

Comment: I just tried scripting for query but i couldn't access nested values from script... @Val

Comment: Now i have this problem —> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022283/elasticsearch-search-query-why-params-source-nested-field-size-is-not-workin

Comment: @Vedat I've answered that linked question. Let me know whether you still need help w/ this one.

Comment: @JoeSorocin I guess with that there will be some performance problems. What do you think about perfomance ?

Comment: I think scripting is meant to be the last resort. Try to prepare your data such that scripting won't be necessary in the first place... But generally speaking, let's not overthink and prematurely optimize. I don't really think about performance before I've encountered actual bottlenecks...

Comment: You’re right. On the other side , There will be over 10k doc. And every doc will include dayData. Do you have another idea over my structure? @JoeSorocin