# Can I filter document from nested key value in Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

We want to have a solution to compare a nested key value with root level field. Can we access a nested key value for filter(script)? We can get value from script field(parms), but we can't use parms in filter function. Only doc can be used from my knowledge, but doc in filter script we can't access nested structure.  If doc under nested path, the meanwhile we can't access root level field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could leverage the [`copy_to`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/copy-to.html) / [`include_in_root`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-params) parameters in order to allow `_source` access in a script, as I've outlined in my answer to [How to iterate through a nested array in elasticsearch with filter script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64447956/8160318)

Alternatively, you could hijack a [`function_score` query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) which, unlike standard filters, *still* has access to `params._source` without any mapping adjustments. Discussed in more detail [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65810028/8160318).

Comment: I have go through your solution,I need to filter not only value. for example key==name and value==John not only value==John.

Comment: Re-read the 2nd suggestion then. It allows you to iterate objects in an array and achieve the `AND` query you're after.

Comment: Nice, you got it!