# Filtering empty or non empty array in Elasticsearch Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

How can I search for an empty array or non empty array field in Kibana? To be more precise: There is an api that is used for queries and these requests/responses are logged. The search may result in an empty array if no elements have been found: 'response: []'. In other cases this "Response" field is an array populated with objects: 'response: [{"myProp": "something"}, {"myProp": "something2"}]'.
I've tried to use DSL queries, nested searches and other Stackoverflow answers but without success.
For the following I get syntax error (or for any other solution I try to use) in the Kibana DSL query:

```
"must_not": {
  "script": {
    "script": "response.size() > 0"
  }
}
```

or using the following results in an Internal Server Error:

```
{
  "script": "response.size > 0"
}
```

[image]

Comment: The best thing to do is to add another integer field containing the number of results you have in the array. Then the query simply becomes a range query on that field checking for == 0 or > 0. Much more performant than messing with scripts.

Answer (score 1):

If your `response` field **is **NOT** defined as [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)**, you'll need to target one of the array objects' keys instead of the array itself. You should preferably pick a key that's present in all of the child objects -- in your case `myProp`.

Now, if `myProp` has a [defined `keyword` sub-mapping](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#text-multi-fields), you could do:

```json
{
  "script": {
    "script": {
      "source": "doc['response.myProp'].size() > 0",
      "lang": "painless"
    }
  }
}
```

which basically says, look at the length of the [doc values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-doc-vals) array and infer the parent array length based on that.

---

If your `response` **is indeed [`nested`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html)**, it gets even tricker. I've explained the reasons in my answers to:

- [Elasticsearch search query: why params._source.nested_field.size() is not working in script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54022283/elasticsearch-search-query-why-params-source-nested-field-size-is-not-workin/65810028#65810028)
- and [How to iterate through a nested array in elasticsearch with filter script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64447956/how-to-iterate-through-a-nested-array-in-elasticsearch-with-filter-script/64452344#64452344)

but the principle stays the same — you'd extract the contents of the nested array objects onto a flattened level where it's easier to compute the resulting array length.

Comment: Now I have better understanding of these kind of objects. Right now creating indexes, is out of scope for me; I could not filter the data that works as intended. On the bright side I had no syntax error nor server error, so this gave me the right direction.

Comment: Ok, I’m glad you have a better understanding now!