# Select documents by array of objects when at least one object doesn't contain necessary field Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query, elasticsearch-painless, elasticsearch-scripting

I have documents in the elasticsearch and can't understand how to apply search script that should return documents if any **attachment** doesn't contain uuid or uuid is null. Version of elastic 5.2.
Mapping of documents

```
"mappings": {
    "documentType": {
        "properties": {
            "attachment": {
                "properties": {
                    "uuid": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "path": {
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    "size": {
                        "type": "long"
                    }
                }
            }}}
```

In the elasticsearch it looks like

```
{
        "_index": "documents",
        "_type": "documentType",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "attachment": [
               {
                "uuid": "21321321",
                "path": "../uploads/somepath",
                "size":1231
               },
               {
                "path": "../uploads/somepath",
                "size":1231
               },      
         ]},
{
        "_index": "documents",
        "_type": "documentType",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "attachment": [
               {
                "uuid": "223645641321321",
                "path": "../uploads/somepath",
                "size":1231
               },
               {
                "uuid": "22341424321321",
                "path": "../uploads/somepath",
                "size":1231
               },        
         ]},
{
        "_index": "documents",
        "_type": "documentType",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 1.0,
        "_source": {
          "attachment": [
               {
                "uuid": "22789789341321321",
                "path": "../uploads/somepath",
                "size":1231
               }, 
               {
                "path": "../uploads/somepath",
                "size":1231
               },      
         ]}
```

As result I want to get attachments with _id 1 and 3. But as result I get error of the script
I tried to apply next script:

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "attachment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "inline": "for (item in doc['attachment'].value) { if (item['uuid'] == null) { return true}}",
                            "lang": "painless"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Error is next:

```
 "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "runtime error",
                "script_stack": [
                    "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:77)",
                    "org.elasticsearch.search.lookup.LeafDocLookup.get(LeafDocLookup.java:36)",
                    "for (item in doc['attachment'].value) { ",
                    "                 ^---- HERE"
                ],
                "script": "for (item in doc['attachment'].value) { if (item['uuid'] == null) { return true}}",
                "lang": "painless"
            }
        ],
```

Is it possible to select documents in case even one attachment object doesn't contain uuid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterating arrays of objects is not as trivial as one would expect. I've written extensively about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66957242/8160318) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66801944/8160318).

Since your `attachments` are not defined as `nested`, ES will internally represent them as flattened lists of values (also called "doc values"). For instance `attachment.uuid` in doc#2 will become `["223645641321321", "22341424321321"]`, and `attachments.size` will turn into `[1231, 1231]`.

This means that you can simply **compare the `.length`** of these flattened representations! I assume `attachment.size` will **always** be present and can be thus taken as the comparison baseline.

One more thing. To take advantage of these optimized doc values for textual fields, it'll [require one small mapping change](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.12/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param):

```json
PUT documents/documentType/_mappings
{
  "properties": {
    "attachment": {
      "properties": {
        "uuid": {
          "type": "text",
          "fielddata": true     <---
        },
        "path": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "size": {
          "type": "long"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When that's done and you've reindexed your docs — which can be done with this little [Update by query trick](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update-by-query.html#picking-up-a-new-property):

```json
POST documents/_update_by_query
```

You can then use the following script query:

```json
POST documents/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "attachment"
          }
        },
        {
          "script": {
            "script": {
              "inline": "def size_field_length = doc['attachment.size'].length; def uuid_field_length =  doc['attachment.uuid'].length; return uuid_field_length < size_field_length",
              "lang": "painless"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your response. I will check it and looks for future I will make reindex for attachment that change type on nested.

Comment: You're welcome. Making the attachments nested is a good approach. Just keep in mind that scripting with `nested` fields is a chapter of its own. The links at the top of my answer should point you to the right direction, though!

Comment: It works. I have reindexed and run your script and it works. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Just to supplement [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67088155/5168341). If mapping for *uuid* field was created automatically elastic search adds it in this way:

```
"uuid": {
    "type": "text",
    "fields": {
        "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
        }
    }
}
```

then script could look like:

```
POST documents/_search
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "exists": {
                        "field": "attachment"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "script": {
                        "script": {
                            "inline": "doc['attachment.size'].length > doc['attachment.uuid.keyword'].length",
                            "lang": "painless"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are right, your suggestion also works fine even without reindexing